# Move circle in a circular path like knob tune

Tags: ios, math

How to move circle in a circular path like knob tune?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Do you want to move by degrees or by distance? Do you know your starting point on the circle, and do you have an assumed center point? More details, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
xcord = centerX+(radius*cos(theta))
ycord = centerY+(radius*cos(theta))


put the circle in (xcord,ycord)

increment theta by a small radian value.......
```